# Grails 2.5 REST PUT not getting called

Tags: json, grails

Grails 2.4 RESTful controller.

I have a basic question. I have a RESTful controller with simple domain class and my GET, POST works fine. 
How do I send PUT JSON request?
I am using default RESTful generated controllers

```
url -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"roleId":1,"username":"testuser5"}' http://localhost:8090/testapp/User
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 02:07:13 GMT

{"id":null,"userId":79,"username":"testuser5"}
```

Then I tried PUT using same above JSON response (removed id:null and changed the username):

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"userId":79,"username":"testuser6"}' http://localhost:8090/testapp/User
```

Request goes to index and I get list of users. What I am doing wrong? How do I invoke "update' method? If I add my own method and I do PUT, my own method gets invoked.

Domain class:

```
class User {
    Integer userId
    String username

    static mapping = {
        table 'user'
        version false
        id name:'userId', column: 'user_id'
    }

    static constraints = {
        username blank:false, nullable:false
    }
}
```

RESTful controller:

```
class UserController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond User.list(params), model:[userInstanceCount: User.count()]
    }
    def show(User userInstance) {
        respond userInstance
    }
    def create() {
        respond new User(params)
    }

     @Transactional
    def update(User userInstance) {
        println "*** in update "
        if (userInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (userInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond userInstance.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        userInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'User.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
                redirect userInstance
            }
            '*'{ respond userInstance, [status: OK] }
        }
    }

    protected void notFound() {
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])
                redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the call to `user.validate()` prior to calling `hasErrors()`. See

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy#L99

Comment: I have added prinln on very first line in 'update' method and I don't see it when I called PUT with curl. How should I call update?? At the begining of controller I have:                                   static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]        I have also I added validate as you mentioned but no luck.

Comment: Your URL you are passing to the PUT request is missing the id

Comment: What about if you don't have an ID, for example when the ID is generated by the server and returned by the PUT method?